# How can I create a company-wide shared calendar in Office365 or SharePoint that can be accessed in Outlook and OWA?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calendar

How can I create a company-wide shared calendar in Office365 or SharePoint that can be accessed in Outlook and OWA?

I am looking for the simplest MS-supported option.

Answer (score 1):

One way of accomplishing half of your question is to make a Calendar in a SharePoint site that everyone in your organization has access to. Assuming someone can view the calendar app in said SharePoint site, the "Connect to Outlook" button in the Calendar tab of the Calendar app will sync the calendar with Outlook 2013. I didn't have any luck getting the calendar to show up in OWA, though, so there may be a better answer out there.

Comment: in OWA under other calendars you can just past in the full Link to the SharePoint Calendar.  It should then show up just like personal calendar.

Comment: I'm not sure where to paste the link? I don't see an option for that.

Comment: When you logon to OWA just below your calendar is an option to add a calendar.  Click the "+" icon and a text box is available for you to past the SharePoint URL in.

Answer (score 1):

Another option In O365 if you are using OWA you can create calendars directly in the interface and share the calendar.

Go to the Calendar interface and create a new calendar with the "+" icon
[image]

In the upper right hand corner - select Share
[image]

Add the users or groups you will share with and they will get an email.  The email will contain a link to the calendar as well as a link that will add it Outlook Web Access.

Comment: I've tried this, and it works with OWA, however Outlook seems to have a bug and can't connect with the shared calendar. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2990457

Comment: The workaround in the KB, didn't work for me. I haven't tried the hotfix yet.